# Liquibase and migrating from HSQL 1.8.0.x to HSQL 2.2.8 can't drop column

Tags: hsqldb, liquibase

I've been running Liquibase for both mySQL (for the real stuff) and HSQLDB (for testing).  I recently had to update our Hibernate version, which required me to update our HSQLDB version to 2.x.x - I went with the latest.  Now I have at least one changeset that was running fine before, but now gives me:

> Error executing SQL ALTER TABLE app_user DROP COLUMN name: column is
>   referenced in: PUBLIC.SYS_CT_10302 in statement [ALTER TABLE app_user
>   DROP COLUMN name]

The column "name" does have a unique constraint on it (along with another column) at the time it is being dropped, so I suspect that is the problem.  However, the unique constraint doesn't have a name, so I haven't had any success dropping it first, either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the name of the UNIQUE constraint by querying the INFORMATION_SCHEMA:

```
SELECT CONSTRAINT_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE WHERE COLUMN_NAME = 'NAME' AND TABLE_NAME = 'APP_USER'

ALTER TABLE APP_USER DROP CONSTRAINT ...
```

Alternatively, you can drop the column together with any constraints that use it:

```
ALTER TABLE APP_USER DROP COLUMN NAME CASCADE
```

Comment: Thanks.  I swear I tried the CASCADE option and got some sort of permission problem which didn't make any sense in my in-memory database, but I tried it again and it worked, so it must have been some other error.